# How to get the value of an element and evaluate if it is negative in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I want to check if the value -4.55 highlighted in the picture is negative.
This is the HTML code

[image]

So I tried `cy.get('span[class="ng-binding"]').invoke('text').then((text) => { expect(text).to.be.lessThan(0)})`
But it seems this is not the correct syntax.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your locator is correct and you successfully get '-4.55' in text variable. The next thing you have to do is convert the text into a number. You can use [parseInt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to do that:

```
cy.get('span[class="ng-binding"]').invoke('text').then((text) => {
    expect(parseInt(text)).to.be.lessThan(0)
})
```

Comment: tks @alapan indeed. I just did a small modification. Instead of using ```cy.get(('span[class="ng-binding"]'))``` I used ```cy.get("[iscroll-tap-stop='lineprice()'] > span:nth-of-type(1)").invoke('text').then(parseFloat).should('be.lessThan',0)``` It worked.

Comment: `parseInt()` would have also worked in your case. I see you changed the locator, I was skeptical as well with the locator originally mentioned as I could see two instances of the same class. hence I mentioned in the question that assuming your locators are correct. Anyways glad it worked out for you in the end.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-binding` appears on many elements in an Angluar app. You would be better to choose something more specific, even if the Cypress command is longer.

Also, when selecting by class you can use a shorter syntax of the pattern `element.class`. This has an advantage if there are multiple classes present.

For instance,

```js
cy.get('a.receipt-item__input')
  .children().eq(0)
  .invoke('text')
  .should('contain', '-')
```

Checking for a negative sign is an alternative to parsing to numeric, would be better to avoid a conversion error if the text has non-numeric charaters (e.g currency symbol).